# How to connect to ElasticSearch on AWS via reactivesearch-proxy-server

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, proxy-server

I'm setting up my first ElasticSearch app using ReactiveSearch to connect to an ElasticSearch index I created on AWS.
I'm new to Node.js and most of the technology involved here. I think I have a basic ReactiveSearch app that works but it won't connect to my AWS ElasticSearch index. When I enter a search I get no output and no errors.

I followed the ReactiveSearch Quickstart guide:
https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivesearch.html

I created the Boilerplate App with CRA:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app

The app runs ok but there is no output when I try to search.
Then I saw the note that you have to use a proxy with AWS. I cloned https://github.com/appbaseio-apps/reactivesearch-proxy-server and got that working and I now have a proxy that runs on `http://localhost:7777/`

My Search App connects to the proxy like this:

```
<ReactiveBase
  app="my-search"
  url="http://localhost:7777">
```

This is the code that sets the target in the proxy. I commented out the authorisation because I'm not using appbase.io.

```
const options = {
    target: 'https://search....ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com',
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req) => {
/*        proxyReq.setHeader( 
            'Authorization',
            `Basic ${btoa('cf7QByt5e:d2d60548-82a9-43cc-8b40-93cbbe75c34c')}`
        );*/
        /* transform the req body back from text */
        const { body } = req;
        if (body) {
            if (typeof body === 'object') {
                proxyReq.write(JSON.stringify(body));
            } else {
                proxyReq.write(body);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the ReactiveSearch app on my browser at `http://localhost:3000`

When I type keywords into the search box I see output like this in the proxy app:

```
Verifying requests ✔ {"preference":"results"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"cables","fields":["Description"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"or","fuzziness":0}},{"multi_match":{"query":"cables","fields":["Description"],"type":"phrase_prefix","operator":"or"}}],"minimum_should_match":"1"}}]}}]}},"size":50,"_source":{"includes":["*"],"excludes":[]},"from":0}

Verifying requests ✔ {"preference":"SearchBox"}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"horse","fields":["Description"],"type":"best_fields","operator":"or","fuzziness":0}},{"multi_match":{"query":"horse","fields":["Description"],"type":"phrase_prefix","operator":"or"}}],"minimum_should_match":"1"}}}}]}},"size":20}
```

What am I missing to get the connection working? Do I need to add some kind of authentication in AWS and add passwords to the proxy code?

Is there a way to see some debugging info?

Thanks,
Phil